# django url not working when directions followed

Tags: django

This is driving me crazy. Everything looks good. I am getting this error:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/home
Using the URLconf defined in gds.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^fixiss/
The current URL, home, didn't match any of these.

Here is my root url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^fixiss/', include('fixiss.urls')),

]
```

My app url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name="index"),
]
```

And the view in my app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Home page!")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "app url" module is `'fixiss.urls'` where you only have one pattern (the empty string) and you are you are including it under `fixiss/`, the only match should be:

```
http://localhost:8000/fixiss/
```

If you change your one pattern to:

```
url(r'^home$', views.home, name="index")
```

that view will be served under

```
http://localhost:8000/fixiss/home/
```

The actual name of the `view` function (`home` in this case) is rather irrelevant when it comes to url pattern matching. What counts is the specified regex pattern.

This is very well documented:

- [Django url dispatching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls) in general
- [Including urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) in particular

Comment: I agree with this

Answer (score 0):

That is because no url matches `home/`. Your url should be `http://localhost:8000/fixiss/`

In the app's (fixiss) url file, the regex is empty meaning, it does not expect a string after `fixiss/` in the url for it to match.

Comment: Thanks Evans. I see the issue. Actually the tutorial I was following had it wrong. I'm a beginner so, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks schwobasegg, I'll check those links out.